# Overall tax in invoice consolibite quickbook sdk in php

Tags: php, sdk, quickbooks-online

I am using consolibyte Quickbook online version for php.
I am creating the invoice and it is working fine for me.
And I am include tax in line. but I have to remove that tax and want to add in overall tax.
Can someone please help me.

Everything is working fine I just want to add tax same as attached image.
Please help
Thanks in advance

My code for add the invoice :

public function addInvoice($invoiceArray,$chargeArray,$customerRef,$db_product,$invoice_id,$other_charges,$price_grid,$payment,$orderId,$quickbook_id,$display_order_id,$payment_terms_name,$payment_terms_day){

```
     $IPP = new \QuickBooks_IPP($this->QBO_DSN);

    // Get our OAuth credentials from the database
    $creds = $this->IntuitAnywhere->load(Session::get('useremail'), Session::get('user_id'));
    // Tell the framework to load some data from the OAuth store
    $IPP->authMode(
        \QuickBooks_IPP::AUTHMODE_OAUTH,
        Session::get('useremail'),
        $creds);

    if ($this->is_sandbox) {
        // Turn on sandbox mode/URLs
        $IPP->sandbox(true);
    }
    // This is our current realm
    $this->realm = $creds['qb_realm'];

    // Load the OAuth information from the database
    $this->context = $IPP->context();


    $InvoiceService = new \QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();


    if($quickbook_id > 0) {
        $retr = $InvoiceService->delete($this->context, $this->realm, $quickbook_id);
    }


    $Invoice = new \QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Invoice();

    $CustomField = new \QuickBooks_IPP_Object_CustomField();
    $CustomField->setDefinitionId('2');
    $CustomField->setName('Sales Rep');
    $CustomField->setType('StringType');
    $CustomField->setStringValue($invoiceArray[0]->sales_name);
    $Invoice->addCustomField($CustomField);




    $CustomField1 = new \QuickBooks_IPP_Object_CustomField();
    $CustomField1->setDefinitionId('1');
    $CustomField1->setName('Customer PO');
    $CustomField1->setType('StringType');
    $CustomField1->setStringValue($invoiceArray[0]->custom_po);
    $Invoice->addCustomField($CustomField1);




     $Invoice->setDocNumber('INV-' . $display_order_id);

     $Invoice->setTxnDate(date('Y-m-d'));



     if($payment_terms_name != '') {


        if($payment_terms_day > 0) {
            $due_day = $payment_terms_day;
        } else {
            $due_day = 0;
        }


     $TermService = new \QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Term();

     $terms = $TermService->query($this->context, $this->realm, "SELECT * FROM Term WHERE Name = '".$payment_terms_name."' ");
     $Term = new \QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Term();

            $payment_terms_id = 0;
            if(!empty($terms)){

                $Term = $terms[0];
                $payment_terms_id = $Term->getId();
                $payment_terms_id = str_replace('{','',$payment_terms_id);
                $payment_terms_id = str_replace('}','',$payment_terms_id);
                $payment_terms_id = abs($payment_terms_id);
            }

            if($payment_terms_id > 0) {
            $Invoice->setSalesTermRef($payment_terms_id);
            } else {
                $Term->setName($payment_terms_name);
                $Term->setDueDays($due_day);
                if ($resp = $TermService->add($this->context, $this->realm, $Term))
                 {
                    $payment_terms_id = $this->getId($resp);
                    $Invoice->setSalesTermRef($payment_terms_id);
                 }

            }

            if($due_day > 0) {

              $setDate  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+".$due_day. "days"));
              $Invoice->setDueDate($setDate);

            } else {

              $Invoice->setDueDate(date('Y-m-d'));
            }
     }




    foreach ($invoiceArray as $key => $value) {

            $desc = array();

            foreach ($value->sizeData as  $sizeAll) {
               $desc[] = $sizeAll->size.'('.$sizeAll->qnty.')'; 
            }

            $description = implode(', ' , $desc);

            $product_name_desc_display = $value->product_name.' : '.$value->color_name.' : '.$description;


             $Line = new \QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
             $Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
             $Line->setAmount($value->total_line_charge * $value->total_qnty);
             $Line->setDescription($product_name_desc_display);

             $SalesItemLineDetail = new \QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
             if($value->vendor_id == 1) {
                 $SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef($db_product[0]->ss);
             } else {
                 $SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef($db_product[0]->custom_product);
             }

             $SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice($value->total_line_charge);
             $SalesItemLineDetail->setQty($value->total_qnty);


             $Line->addSalesItemLineDetail($SalesItemLineDetail);

             $Invoice->addLine($Line);

             $Invoice->setCustomerRef($customerRef);

     }



     if($chargeArray[0]->order_total != 0 && $chargeArray[0]->order_total != '') {

             $Line = new \QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
             $Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
             $Line->setAmount($chargeArray[0]->tax);
             $Line->setDescription('Tax-'.$chargeArray[0]->tax_rate);

             $SalesItemLineDetail = new \QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
             $SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef($db_product[0]->tax_charge);
             $SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice($chargeArray[0]->tax);
             $SalesItemLineDetail->setQty(1);
             $Line->addSalesItemLineDetail($SalesItemLineDetail);
             $Invoice->addLine($Line);
             $Invoice->setCustomerRef($customerRef);
     }

     if($chargeArray[0]->discount != 0 && $chargeArray[0]->discount != '') {

             $Line = new \QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
             $Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
             $Line->setAmount(-$chargeArray[0]->discount);
             $Line->setDescription('Discount');

             $SalesItemLineDetail = new \QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
             $SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef($db_product[0]->discount_charge);
             $SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice(-$chargeArray[0]->discount);
             $SalesItemLineDetail->setQty(1);
             $Line->addSalesItemLineDetail($SalesItemLineDetail);
             $Invoice->addLine($Line);
             $Invoice->setCustomerRef($customerRef);
     }



    if ($resp = $InvoiceService->add($this->context, $this->realm, $Invoice))
    {
        $qb_invoice_id =  $this->getId($resp);
         $this->common->UpdateTableRecords('invoice',array('id' => $invoice_id),array('qb_id' => $qb_invoice_id));

         //if($quickbook_id > 0) {
                 $this->common->UpdateTableRecords('payment_history',array('order_id' => $orderId),array('qb_id' => $qb_invoice_id,'qb_flag' => 0));
        // }


        return 1; 
    }
    else
    {

        return 0; 

    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AqQy.png)